# Is it possible to use rolling cross validation with cv.glmnet in R?

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation, glmnet

I have time series data similar to the following:

```
dates <- as.character(seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "days"))
predictor <- rnorm(length(dates))
target <- rnorm(length(dates))
data <- data.frame(matrix(c(dates, predictor, target), ncol = 3))
names(data) <- c("period", "predictor", "target")
data <- data %>%
  mutate(period = as.Date(period),
         predictor = as.numeric(predictor),
         target = as.numeric(target))
```

I want to fit a Ridge regression to this data using `cv.glmnet` per the below:

```
mod <- cv.glmnet(model.matrix(target ~ predictor, data),
                 data$target,
                 alpha = 0,
                 standardize = T)
```

However, instead of using regular n-fold cross validation as built in with `cv.glmnet`, I would like to use some sort of rolling cross validation. I.e. using the 11th observation to validate a model trained on the first ten observations etcetera.

I know that this can be solved using the `caret` package, but is there a solution using `cv.glmnet`?